# elements (i.e. a, div, h1) on page move when zooming in with android emulator and browser

Tags: android, html, css, android-emulator, zooming

Note: I'm using jQuery and jQuery Mobile.

I have a mobile page which seems to work okay in iOS, as far as respecting elements' positioning when zooming (or pinching).  In Android, this is another story.  Employing the Android SDK Emulator, all of my content is getting squeezed.  I know there's a way to enforce that the content does not shift when zooming; I've seen it on desktop websites while using the Android browser.  Disabling zooming is not the answer because I have an image on the page and I want the user to zoom in on said image.

To sum up:

- I want to keep all content undisturbed when zooming (enlarging).

Thank you very much for any help.

Here is the full page (including css):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test Mobile Page</title>
    <meta name="description" content="This is a test page." />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=10.0, user-scalable=yes">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />

    <style type="text/css">

      #header {
        background: blue bottom left repeat-x;
        padding: 3px 5px 0 5px;
      }

      .BackBtn {
        float:left;
      }

      .IndexBtn {
        float:right;
      }

      .ui-body-c {
        background-color: #EEF3F8;
      }

      .ui-btn {
        font-size: 0.8em;
      }

      .ui-btn-inner {
        padding: .6em 10px;
      }

      h2 {
        background: silver bottom left repeat-x;
        color:#333;
        font-weight:bold;
        line-height:1em;
        clear:both;
      }

      h4 {
        clear: both;
      }

      #Content #TableDiv TH, #Content #TableDiv TD {
        border:1px solid;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        border-color:rgb(153,153,153);
      }

      #Content #TableDiv TD {
        background:#FFF;
      }

      #Content #TableDiv TH {
        padding: 5px;
        background: #F0F0E0;
        border-top: 1px solid #999;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
      }

      img {
        clear: both;
      }

    </style>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div data-role="page" id="Index">
      <div id="header">
        <h1>Title</h1>
      </div>

      <a href="JavaScript:history.back();" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-inline="true" class="BackBtn">Back</a>
      <a href="#Index" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-inline="true" class="IndexBtn">Home</a>

      <h2>Section</h2>

      <h4 id="Article1">Article1</h4>
      <h4 id="Article2">Article2</h4>
      <h4 id="Article3">Article3</h4>

      <div id="Content">
        <div id="TableDiv">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Column 1</th>
              <th>Column 2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Value 1</td>
              <td>Value 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Value 3</td>
              <td>Value 4</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>

      <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/Rotating_earth_(large).gif/200px-Rotating_earth_(large).gif"/>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Update**

I figured out if I specify a set width on the page like this:

```
 <div data-role="page" id="Index" style="width:320px;">
```

The zooming does not disturb the contents of the page.

But I want to maintain a liquid layout, or a fluid (hybrid) layout, at best.  I can use JavaScript to specify the width of the div to the width of the device.  Other than JavaScript, or setting a specific pixel (or em) width in CSS, is there an equivalent method using a liquid layout design?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out if I specify a set width on the page like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="Index" style="width:320px;">
```

The zooming does not disturb the contents of the page.

Unfortunately, if the orientation changes, then this won't be helpful, especially when zooming.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest opening one of those desktop websites you are talking about and cheeking there hrml and css with some browser plugin . thats what i do all the time :)